# Is a Bluetooth laser Rangefinder seen as a keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth, external-keyboard

I could not find the information online. There are many laser Rangefinder that comes with Bluetooth and an application. But I wonder if those device are/could be seen like a regular keyboard. I mean getting a distance will send it to the smartphone as if the user had typed it (what most barcode scanner does).

Is it the most common behavior ? Does only some of them do that? Or not any?

I'm working on a webapp and getting dimensions from real world directly into the app would be nice.

Please answer only if you have seen one working. Thx.

Comment: You can buy portable laser keyboards that work on this design.

Answer (score 0):

because it has the capability to hold only one devices and it has a good battery talktime(life). Yes,it is a common behavior.

Comment: Have you tried one ? Which model ?

Comment: i have a samsung one. it also like that.

Comment: I try to find a Samsung rangefinder there are none. So I checked your profile. You just appear 2 hours ago and answered lot of question with crap. Please, stop polluting this website, you will earn nothing doing that. Read the questions, and just answer when you are sure it's a proper answer. Thx